# Cannot connect to WiFi • MAC address unavailable every time after restart

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, mac-address, pac-rom

Since some days it doesn't load my MAC - so I cannot connect to WiFi.
If I remove everything in `/data/misc/wifi` folder and restart again it works again..

Of course I've to save WiFi networks.

*I'm using PAC ROM on my S3 (with root).*

**UPDATE**

now if I restore / copy my backup files and turn WiFi on it got overwritten by default / empty files

is there a better or **quicker** way to do that?

**UPDATE (150708)**

found that blog: [MAC address unavailable](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-lg-phoenix-thrive/86381-mac-address-unavailable.html)
I think that my kernel/modem/... is defect.
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Dors not load your MAC? What do you see when you go to Settings -> About -> Status?

Comment: "Not available"

Comment: And in a terminal `cat /proc/net/dev`?

Comment: what do you want to hear? | wlan 0 0 0 ...

Comment: What ROM are you on? Do you have root?

Comment: post updated also with phone model